# wso2is SingleLogoutProfile POST binding

Tags: spring-security, logout, saml-2.0, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I wonder how much wso2is is conformant with the saml2 SSO specification. specially considering SingleLogoutProfile with POST binding. After one SP initiates a logout, the IS identifies the participating SPs to log out as well, and sends each of them a LogoutRequest directly via HTTP.

bellow I am reproducing an image from the specification ([line 1161](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf)). Note step 3 and also note the greyed out User-Agent. It is greyed out because the SOAP-binding bypasses the user-agent and sends requests directly to the session participants. POST-binding however is supposed to work with the involvement of the User-Agent! ( [line 765](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf))

[image: SAML SLO PROFILE]

I use wso2is 4.6.0, with spring-security-saml-extension RC2. When the spring-extension receives a LogoutRequest (step 3), it assumes that there is a logged in user, which can only be if the http-request is coming from the user-agent! Otherwise the SPs have to maintain some kind of a table linking global-session-ids to local-session-ids and look up which session to terminate on receiving a logoutrequest. This approach is also recommended in this [blog](http://soasecurity.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/).

So either I am misunderstanding the saml2-specs or the wso2 guys are! I rather believe its me, so somebody please enlighten me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP-POST is a front-channel binding and its message exchanges must go through the User-Agent and use HTML form.

In case wso2is makes the POST call directly to the SingleLogout endpoint (in a similar fashion as SOAP binding - without involvement of the user agent), they are unfortunately not following the spec. This might lead to interoperability issues, just like the one you're experiencing.